# Access cookies on SSR for @angular/ssr

Tags: angular, angular-ssr

I am using AWS Cognito as my authentication provider and I am also trying out the new @angular/ssr package from Angular 17. As I try to use Guards to protect my routes, I am trying to keep the user session into the Cookies so that later on I can use them in the Server Side of the Guard in order to know if the user can access or not to the route.

So far I have not been able to access cookies when the guard is loaded into the server side, can someone help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: where are your scripts, will you add more details to your question?